# When a GString will change its toString representation

Tags: groovy, closures, tostring, assert, gstring

I am reading the Groovy closure documentation in https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#this. Having a question regarding with GString behavior.

> 4. Closures in GStrings

The document mentioned the following:

Take the following code:

```
def x = 1
def gs = "x = ${x}"
assert gs == 'x = 1'
```

The code behaves as you would expect, but what happens if you add:

```
x = 2
assert gs == 'x = 2'
```

You will see that the assert fails! There are two reasons for this:

a GString only evaluates lazily the toString representation of values

the syntax ${x} in a GString does not represent a closure but an expression to $x, evaluated when the GString is created.

In our example, the GString is created with an expression referencing x. When the GString is created, the value of x is 1, so the GString is created with a value of 1. When the assert is triggered, the GString is evaluated and 1 is converted to a String using toString. When we change x to 2, we did change the value of x, but it is a different object, and the GString still references the old one.

> A GString will only change its toString representation if the values it references are mutating. If the references change, nothing will happen.

My question is regarding the above-quoted explanation, in the example code, 1 is obviously a value, not a reference type, then if this statement is true, it should update to 2 in the GString right?

The next example listed below I feel also a bit confusing for me (the last part)
why if we mutate Sam to change his name to Lucy, this time the GString is correctly mutated??
I am expecting it won't mutate?? why the behavior is so different in the two examples?

```
class Person {
    String name
    String toString() { name }          
}

def sam = new Person(name:'Sam')        
def lucy = new Person(name:'Lucy')      
def p = sam                             
def gs = "Name: ${p}"                   
assert gs == 'Name: Sam'                
p = Lucy. //if we change p to Lucy                                
assert gs == 'Name: Sam'   // the string still evaluates to Sam because it was the value of p when the GString was created
/* I would expect below to be 'Name: Sam' as well 
 * if previous example is true. According to the     
 * explanation mentioned previously. 
 */         
sam.name = 'Lucy' // so if we mutate Sam to change his name to Lucy                  
assert gs == 'Name: Lucy'  // this time the GString is correctly mutated
```

Why the comment says 'this time the GString is correctly mutated? In previous comments it just metioned

> the string still evaluates to Sam because it was the value of p when the GString was created, the value of p is 'Sam' when the String was created

thus I think it should not change here??
Thanks for kind help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two examples explain two different use cases. In the first example, the expression `"x = ${x}"` creates a `GString` object that internally stores `strings =  ['x = ']` and `values = [1]`. You can check internals of this particular `GString` with `println gs.dump()`:

```
<org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl@6aa798b strings=[x = , ] values=[1]>
```

Both objects, a `String` one in the `strings` array, and an `Integer` one in the `values` array are **immutable**. (Values are immutable, not arrays.) When the `x` variable is assigned to a new value, it creates a new object in the memory that is not associated with the `1` stored in the `GString.values` array. `x = 2` is not a mutation. This is new object creation. This is not a Groovy specific thing, this is how Java works. You can try the following pure Java example to see how it works:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Integer number = 2;
list.add(number);

number = 4;

System.out.println(list); // prints: [2]
```

The use case with a `Person` class is different. Here you can see how mutation of an object works. When you change `sam.name` to `Lucy`, you mutate an internal stage of an object stored in the `GString.values` array. If you, instead, create a new object and assigned it to `sam` variable (e.g. `sam = new Person(name:"Adam")`), it would not affect internals of the existing `GString` object. The object that was stored internally in the `GString` did not mutate. The variable `sam` in this case just refers to a different object in the memory. When you do `sam.name = "Lucy"`, you mutate the object in the memory, thus `GString` (which uses a reference to the same object) sees this change. It is similar to the following plain Java use case:

```java
List<List<Integer>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

List<Integer> nested = new ArrayList<>();
nested.add(1);

list2.add(nested);
System.out.println(list2); // prints: [[1]]

nested.add(3);

System.out.println(list2); // prints: [[1,3]]

nested = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println(list2); // prints: [[1,3]]
```

You can see that `list2` stores the reference to the object in the memory represented by `nested` variable at the time when `nested` was added to `list2`. When you mutated `nested` list by adding new numbers to it, those changes are reflected in `list2`, because you mutate an object in the memory that `list2` has access to. But when you override `nested` with a new list, you create a new object, and `list2` has no connection with this new object in the memory. You could add integers to this new `nested` list and `list2` won't be affected - it stores a reference to a different object in the memory. (The object that previously could be referred to using `nested` variable, but this reference was overridden later in the code with a new object.)

`GString` in this case behaves similarly to the examples with lists I shown you above. If you mutate the state of the interpolated object (e.g. `sam.name`, or adding integers to `nested` list), this change is reflected in the `GString.toString()` that produces a string when the method is called. (The string that is created uses the current state of values stored in the `values` internal array.) On the other hand, if you override a variable with a new object (e.g. `x = 2`, `sam = new Person(name:"Adam")`, or `nested = new ArrayList()`), it won't change what `GString.toString()` method produces, because it still uses an object (or objects) that is stored in the memory, and that was previously associated with the variable name you assigned to a new object.

Comment: thanks so much for the insightful explain. I feel now understanding the reason behind that result. Really appreciate! I find the list2 is actually nested list, while nested list is a one dimension List, I think that is a typo thing doesn't matter

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, the variable is declared with the correct name, I didn't get it previously. :) I really like the way you explain things, because you used things people are familiar with to explain ideas that is a bit difficult to understand

Comment: Happy to help you, @HuibinZhang :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

That's *almost* the whole story, as you can use a Closure for your GString evaluation, so in place of just using the variable:

```
def gs = "x = ${x}"
```

You can use a closure that returns the variable:

```
def gs = "x = ${-> x}"
```

This means that the value `x` is evaluated at the time the GString is changed to a String, so this then works (from the original question)

```
def x = 1
def gs = "x = ${-> x}"
assert gs == 'x = 1'
x = 2
assert gs == 'x = 2'
```

Comment: thanks mate, I see the reason now. Appreciate your kind help!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the closure example to complete the story! :-)